# is it possible to git clone from one local directory to another local directory on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, git

I have created two directories on my local machine. One is named **dev_projects** and another is named **git_projects**. I have a project folder in **git_projects**. I wanted the project inside the **git_projects** directory to act as a remote git project so that I could git clone from this project to my **dev_projects** directory. I wanted to know if it is really possible.

This is the directory structure

```
dev_projects
    
git_projects
    some_project
```

Once I clone the project I further wished to use git pull and git push commands as well.
For now, I tried to implement this by putting the local directory path as a replacement for the HTTPS link

```
git clone /home/nishant/git_projects/some_project ./
```

But it gives me an error

```
fatal: repository '/home/nishant/git_projects/some_project' does not exist
```

Comment: I’m not quite following. You want to have a Git repo in two locations; one for prod and the other for dev. Is this right? 

Comment: You need to have a `git` server. But I think you should use branches ...

Comment: @pLumo You don't actually need a git server. You are free to to clone from any type of remote, as long as the full URI is a git repository. It can be a local path, a remote server, or even a colleague's machine without any extra git configuration as long as you have access to that repository. (In fact, there's no such thing as a "git server". Things like GitLab, GitHub, etc. just give a UI and proper ssh/https configuration to access remote git repositories)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I just realized my dumb mistake. Actually, I didn't convert my project to a git repo by initializing Git. That's why I wasn't able to use the git commands. If you want to use git clone on a local directory, it's **not** possible.

First, you have to covert the local directory into the local repository by initializing git inside that directory by running the `git init` command. In my case, I should have initialized git inside my `some_project` folder. Now git clone will work.

Comment: In the first paragraph you say, "If you want to use git clone on a local directory, it's **not** possible." while in the second one you explain how it is actually possible (It is possible to clone a local directory as long as that directory is a Git repository).

Comment: Yes, You're right Dan, maybe I should have framed it better but anyways you made it very obvious now.